# how to expandable my Div in Page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have tried all question related to my query but, Unable to find right solution. Now i have found my solution by using `slideToggle`.
now I want my all div to expand on page load.

**Fiddle Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Q4PUw/3767/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$('.expand').click(function(){
    target_num = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    content_id = '#expandable-'.concat(target_num);
    $(content_id).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
    <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to expand first div on load?

Comment: all  div expand first div on load

Comment: you mixup in answer need all div expanded Or only Firstone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your style to:

```
.expandable {
    display:block;
}
```

Now at page load all div are expanded default

Comment: Thank for ans. very nice ans. simple change

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1 :** Place `$( ".expandable:first" ).slideToggle('fast');` on document ready. Which will expand first div on load.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$('.expand').click(function(){
    target_num = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    content_id = '#expandable-'.concat(target_num);
    $(content_id).slideToggle('fast');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".expandable:first" ).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
    <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

**Case 2** : Place `$( ".expandable" ).slideToggle('fast');` on document ready. Which will expand all div on load.

Please check below snippet for more understanding.

```js
$('.expand').click(function(){
    target_num = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    content_id = '#expandable-'.concat(target_num);
    $(content_id).slideToggle('fast');
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".expandable" ).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
    <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:** is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click();
});

$('.expand').click(function(){
    target_num = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
    content_id = '#expandable-'.concat(target_num);
    $(content_id).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

```css
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
    <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>
<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So mark it as solution in order to others that visit this post can find it quick. Cheers! =)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".expandable").slideDown(1000);

})
```

**Final code :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".expandable").slideDown(1000);
    
})
```

```css
.expand {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expandable {
    display:none;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-1">more 1...</p>
</div>

<div class="expandable" id="expandable-1">
  <p>1. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>

<div>
    <p class="expand" id="expand-2">more 2...</p>
</div>

<div class="expandable" id="expandable-2">
    <p>2. This is the content that was hidden before, but now is... Well, visible!"</p>
</div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```